# Drupal RESTful web services to access image URL using Ionic

Tags: rest, ionic-framework, drupal, drupal-7

Firstly, I'm a long time user of stackoverflow for existing answers, first time asker, so go easy if this is too basic or has been answered elsewhere.

I'm trying to use Drupal 7's RESTful web services module to serve content to an Ionic app. I have the content flowing through fine (e.g. title and body text) but am struggling to access the images. The relevant part of the JSON response is:

```
  "field_cover_image": {
    "file": {
      "uri": "http://example.com/drupal/file/9",
      "id": "9",
      "resource": "file"
    }
  },
```

How can I translate that information for use inside an image tag, from what I can see I am only being given the ID of the image at this point where what I need is the url/filename.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create path to original image file (the one user uploaded) from uri with function `file_create_url()` :

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_url/7.x

And you can create path to image file in specific image style with function `image_style_url()`. Second parameter of this function is actually uri, not path.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21image%21image.module/function/image_style_url/7.x

I didn't use Restful Web Service, so I can't tell you how to do that exactly, but you must somehow pass of this uri to one of those 2 functions to get url to image file.